# How to reverse a string that contains complicated emojis?

Tags: javascript, string, emoji

#### Input:

```
Hello world‍‍‍‍
```

#### Desired Output:

```
‍‍‍‍dlrow olleH
```

I tried several approaches but none gave me correct answer.

This failed miserablly:

```js
const text = 'Hello world‍‍‍‍';

const reversed = text.split('').reverse().join('');

console.log(reversed);
```

This kind of works, but it breaks `‍‍‍` into 4 different emojis:

```js
const text = 'Hello world‍‍‍‍';

const reversed = [...text].reverse().join('');

console.log(reversed);
```

I also tried every answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4547609/how-do-you-get-a-string-to-a-character-array-in-javascript), but none of them worked.

How can I get the desired output?

Comment: I can't see the problem with the second solution. What am I missing?

Comment: So these emojis are actually combinatorial emojis somehow, it's quite interesting. First, you have the womans face emoji, which itself is represented by two of your `�` characters, and then there's an extra connecting character, which is charcode 8205, and then there's another two � that represent "red hair", and those 5 characters together mean 'womans face with red hair'

Comment: To properly reverse a string with combined emojis would be pretty complicated, I think. You'd have to check if each emoji is followed by charcode 8205, and if it is you'd have to combine it with the previous emoji instead of treating it as it's own character. Pretty complicated...

Comment: It's very curious that `arr1 = text.split('');` and `arr2 = [...text];` give different arrays, with `arr2` having the two � correctly combined to a single emoji. If you were going to go about using the logic to combine based on charcode 8205, I would use the latter syntax, [...text], as it will be easier to keep the combinations in order

Comment: btw, you can check the the charcode of a single-character string by using `str.charCodeAt(0)` -- the argument is the index of the character

Comment: Javascript confuses me. It's the strangest mix of low and high level language concepts. It's level in that it fully abstracts memory (no pointers, manual memory management), but so low level as to treats strings as dumb code points rather than extended grapheme clusters. It's really confusing, and it makes me never know what to expect when working with this thing.

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica is there any language that *does* splitting by grapheme splitting by default? JS just provides standard strings encoded in UTF-16.

Comment: Could this perhaps be related to unicode Normalization Form Canonical Composition / Decomposition? If expressed in NFC, does each "complicated emoji" sequence condense into a single code point? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45268695/who-performs-unicode-normalization-and-when

Comment: @lights0123 I'm not asking for it to be the default necessarily, but I would expect it to be built into the stdlib of a modern language, particularly one designed for front-end use, where internationalization is so important.  (And to answer the question: yes, Swift does correct grapheme splitting in all string operations. There are some trade-offs, but correctness is usually more important than the downsides, IMO)

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica: JavaScript is explicitly designed as an embeddable scripting language, and I am using the "original" definition of scripting here, as in "programming where most values, types, and operations come from the outside, and you are not in control of the lifetime of most values or even your own program". For a language with that design goal, it makes sense to have a small to non-existent stdlib, so that the types, values, and operations provided by the embedd**ed** stdlib do not interfere with the ones provided by the embedd**ing** host environment. Remember, you cannot …

Comment: … even do I/O in JavaScript, there is no way to read or write a file, there isn't even a way to print text to a console. (Which again makes sense, because depending on where JavaScript is embedded, a concept such as "file" may not even exist, and there may not *be* a console.) JavaScript is used as query language for databases, as configuration language for embedded devices, as extension language for applications. In the REAPER Digital Audio Workstation, it is used to write DSP Algorithms for audio effects. Why would a reverb effect need to know about grapheme clusters?

Comment: @MarkU: No. The redundant code points are mostly legacy, for reasons of roundtrip-compatibility. E.g. the reason why my name can be spelled both with a single `ö` character or a combination of `o` + Umlaut is that, when Unicode was created, they wanted to include every character from every existing widely-used character set. ISO8859-1 and others include the `ö`, so it was added even though it is redundant. For the same reason we have both the Latin o and the Greek omicron even though they have the same glyph, but without having both of them, it would be impossible to convert a document with …

Comment: … ISO8859-7 encoding to Unicode and back without information loss, since ISO8859-7 includes both characters. However, the same is not true for Emoji characters. They are a unique Unicode invention, so there is no need for backwards-compatibility with legacy encodings, and providing precomposed characters for every possible combination of gender, clothing, facial expression, skin color, hair color, etc. would be insane. A simple example are the flag emojis. They are simply a character that says "this is a flag" plus the two character ISO3166-1 Alpha-2 country code.

Comment: Still a work in progress, but maybe we're going to get a native solution in JS for that: https://github.com/tc39/proposal-intl-segmenter - note: some browsers already have this on their nightly versions.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Requirements have changed. It now runs all client side web code, and a scary amount of server-side code (Node.js, Deno). Internationalization is critical, it needs to do it well, or the web will behave incorrectly for non-english users (and in the case of emoji, even english users will suffer the flaws).

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica: In that case, the HTML Spec can specify e.g. a `Text` datatype which works on graphemes. For what my employer is using JS, even the `String` support there is currently is complete overkill. On the other hand, we could desperately need support for units of measure, two-dimensional boolean arrays, enums, and various kinds of timestamps and timespans in nanosecond, microsecond, millisecond, sample, and frame resolution. However, this, in turn doesn't make sense for JS as used as the query, data definition, and schema definition language for CouchDB.

Comment: For an example of what happens if you don't handle this type of situation well, check out a minor issue in Firefox: Create a bookmark that has emojis in the bookmark's title. Now display bookmarks in the sidebar. Finally, resize the sidebar so its width causes it to be at an emoji in the bookmark title. The emoji will get broken up into multiple characters which render incorrectly.

Comment: You may be interested in [this article](https://qntm.org/trick). (The third question there is "How do you reverse a Unicode string?" with the answer being, "You can't." That being said, the article deals with arbitrary Unicode. If you're restricting to English characters and emojis there may be hope. :) )

Comment: @PedroLima ‍‍‍ is [one combined emoji](https://emojipedia.org/family-woman-woman-girl-boy/), yet the individual emojis it consists of gets reversed in the second solution (which wouldn't make sense if you consider it to be one character).

Answer (score 101, accepted):

If you're able to, use the [`_.split()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#split) function provided by [lodash](https://lodash.com/). From [version 4.0](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/Changelog#jan-12-2016--diff--docs) onwards, `_.split()` is capable of splitting unicode emojis.

Using the native `.reverse().join('')` to reverse the 'characters' should work just fine with emojis containing zero-width joiners

```js
function reverse(txt) { return _.split(txt, '').reverse().join(''); }

const text = 'Hello world‍‍‍‍';
console.log(reverse(text));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.20/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-90vH1Z83AJY9DmlWa8WkjkV79yfS2n2Oxhsi2dZbIv0nC4E6m5AbH8Nh156kkM7JePmqD6tcZsfad1ueoaovww==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: The changelogs you point at mention "v4.9.0 - Ensured _.split works with emojis", I think 4.0 might be too early. The comments in the code that is used to split the strings (https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/4.17.15/lodash.js#L261) refer to  https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-unicode which is from 2013. It looks like it has moved on since then, but it does use a pretty hard to decipher lot of unicode regexes. I also can't see any tests in their codebase for unicode splitting. All this would make me wary of using it in production.

Comment: It took only a little searching to find that this fails `reverse("뎌쉐")`  (2 Korean graphemes) which gives "ᅰ셔ᄃ" (3 graphemes).

Comment: It seems there's no easy native solution for this problem. Wouldn't prefer to import a library just for solving this, but it is indeed the most reliable/consistent way to do it at this point.

Comment: Kudos for getting this to work correctly  Reversing writing direction in Firefox on Windows10 still is a wee tad glitchy (the children end up in rear), so lodash beat Windows 10, I guess, which likely a somewhat lower budget 

Comment: @MichaelAnderson You could apply a preliminary `.normalize("NFC")` to prevent Hangul letters from being disassembled (and reassembled in a weird way). It merges letters in a syllable block into one code point.

Comment: @КонстантинВан NFC normalisation is not enough in general. The 2 to 3 grapheme case was simply a quick counter-example that reversing lodash's split did not cover all the cases. There's a lot of other combined characters that have no single character equivalent.

Answer (score 56):

I took TKoL's idea of using the `\u200d` character and used it to attempt to create a smaller script.

***Note:** Not all compositions use a zero width joiner so it will be buggy with other composition characters.*

It uses the traditional `for` loop because we skip some iterations in case we find combined emoticons. Within the `for` loop there is a `while` loop to check if there is a following `\u200d` character. As long there is one we add the next 2 characters as well and forward the `for` loop with 2 iterations so combined emoticons are not reversed.

To easily use it on any string I made it as a new prototype function on the string object.

```js
String.prototype.reverse = function() {
  let textArray = [...this];
  let reverseString = "";

  for (let i = 0; i < textArray.length; i++) {
    let char = textArray[i];
    while (textArray[i + 1] === '\u200d') {
      char += textArray[i + 1] + textArray[i + 2];
      i = i + 2;
    }
    reverseString = char + reverseString;
  }
  return reverseString;
}

const text = "Hello world‍‍‍‍";

console.log(text.reverse());

//Fun fact, you can chain them to double reverse :)
//console.log(text.reverse().reverse());
```

Comment: I was thinking, when you drag and select the text on browsers, `‍‍‍` can only be selected as a whole. How do browsers know it's one character? Is there a built-in way to do it?

Comment: @HaoWu I'm not sure but I guess browsers do it a bit in the same way. These "complex" emoticons just seems to be "simple" emoticons with a so called "zero width joiner" character in between. I'm not sure if it is the browser or the character encoder that combines them together.

Comment: @HaoWu this is what's known as "Unicode Segmentation" on "Grapheme Clusters". Your browser (which may use the one provided by your OS) is going to render and allow selection per grapheme cluster. You can read the spec here: http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr29/#Grapheme_Cluster_Boundaries

Comment: @HaoWu: "How do browsers know it's one character?" – It's *not* "one character". It's multiple characters combining to form a single *grapheme cluster*, rendered as a single *glyph*.

Comment: [Same as here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64136641/how-to-reverse-a-string-that-contains-complicated-emojis#comment113445329_64146120); not all compositions use a zero width joiner.

Comment: This doesn't correctly reverse anything but characters composed with ZWJ. Please, not just here but as a general rule, use external libraries written by people who know what they're doing, instead of hacking up bespoke solutions that happen to work for one test case. The [runes](/a/64151057/5670773) and [lodash](/a/64138318/5670773) libraries were recommended in other answers (I can't vouch for either).

Comment: this will fail with `Aदे` (U+0926) for example

Comment: @benrg I'm all for using existing, tested implementations. But I'm not a big fan of including a whole library if I only need one function from said library. I'd much rather use a modular design that adds only the functions I need, and to serve that code locally, and not actually externally.

Comment: @trlkly - If you import a library written using modules and using a modern compiler, then I would hope that [tree shaking](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/) would solve the issue of dead code for you.

Answer (score 47):

Reversing Unicode text is tricky for a lot of reasons.

First, depending on the programming language, strings are represented in different ways, either as a list of bytes, a list of UTF-16 code units (16 bits wide, often called "characters" in the API), or as ucs4 code points (4 bytes wide).

Second, different APIs reflect that inner representation to different degrees. Some work on the abstraction of bytes, some on UTF-16 characters, some on code points. When the representation uses bytes or UTF-16 characters, there are usually parts of the API that give you access to the elements of this representation, as well as parts that perform the necessary logic to get from bytes (via UTF-8) or from UTF-16 characters to the actual code points.

Often, the parts of the API performing that logic and thus giving you access to the code points have been added later, as first there was 7 bit ascii, then a bit later everybody thought 8 bits were enough, using different code pages, and even later that 16 bits were enough for unicode. The notion of code points as integer numbers without a fixed upper limit was historically added as the fourth common character length for logically encoding text.

Using an API that gives you access to the actual code points seems like that's it. But...

Third, there are a lot of modifier code points affecting the next code point or following code points. E.g. there's a diacritic modifier turning a following a into an ä, e to ë, &c. Turn the code points around, and aë becomes eä, made of different letters. There is a direct representation of e.g. ä as its own code point but using the modifier is just as valid.

Fourth, everything is in constant flux. There are also a lot of modifiers among the emoji, as used in the example, and more are added every year. Therefore, if an API gives you access to the information whether a code point is a modifier, the version of the API will determine whether it already knows a specific new modifier.

Unicode provides a hacky trick, though, for when it's only about the visual appearance:

There are writing direction modifiers. In the case of the example, left-to-right writing direction is used. Just add a right-to-left writing direction modifier at the beginning of the text and depending on the version of the API / browser, it will look correctly reversed

'\u202e' is called right to left override, it is the strongest version of the right to left marker.

See [this explanation by w3.org](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-bidi-unicode-controls)

```
const text = 'Hello world‍‍‍‍'
console.log('\u202e' + text)
```

```js
const text = 'Hello world‍‍‍‍'
let original = document.getElementById('original')
original.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text))
let result = document.getElementById('result')
result.appendChild(document.createTextNode('\u202e' + text))
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif
}
```

```html
<p id="original"></p>
<p id="result"></p>
```

Comment: +1 very creative use of bidi (-:  It's safer to close the override with a POP DIRECTIONAL FORMATTING char `'\u202e' + text + '\u202c'` to avoid affecting following text.

Comment: Thanks  It's quite a hacky trick and the article I linked to goes into a lot of detail explaining why it's way smarter to use the html attributes but this way I could just use string concatenation for my hack 

Comment: Oh, I misread, yes, that would be smarter, too. But making a horrible hack smarter sometimes makes it look more legit, which tends to make it more likely to actually be applied 

Comment: Btw. my firefox on this machine (win 10) doesn't get it entirely right, the children are behind the parents when writing right to left, I guess it's hard to get writing direction right with these massively complex emoji groups-of-people modifiers...

Comment: Another fun edge case: the regional indicator symbols used for flag emojis.  If you take the string "" (the two code points U+1F1E6, U+1F1E8, making the flag for Ascension Island) and try to naively reverse it, you get "", the flag for Canada.

Comment: About the edit requests: I intentionally used the term "characters", as not all UTF-16 characters are code points: some are lower and upper half surrogate pair characters, which is the entire point of UT-16, as oppose to prior Unicode versions that assumes that 16 bits were enough. I'll change it to 2 or 4 bytes, though, thats way better, thanks! ^^ The use of the term ucs4 is deliberate but I will add a clarification :)

Comment: Oh, now I saw it... the internal representation of UTF-16 strings is not made up of 2 or 4 bytes wide code points. It is made up of 2 bytes wide UTF-16 characters. Using the more semantic description in this place would be inaccurate would make it harder to understand what follows. You usually can create any sequence of UTF-16 characters, whether they can be translated to code points or not (like a sequence of five lower half surrogate pair elements)

Comment: @yeoman FYI: "UTF-16 characters" (as you're using the term here) are otherwise known as "UTF-16 code *units*". "Character" tends to be too ambiguous of a term because it can refer to a lot of things (but in the context of Unicode usually a code point).

Comment: Thanks for the better term :) The suggestion of code points was worse than characters (which is at used the term often used by the APIs) but code units is perfect ^^ Just changed it, plus clarification about naming in API)

Answer (score 40):

I know! I'll use RegExp. What could go wrong? (Answer left as an exercise for the reader.)

```js
const text = 'Hello world‍‍‍‍';

const reversed = text.match(/.(\u200d.)*/gu).reverse().join('');

console.log(reversed);
```

Comment: Your answer sounds apologetic but, honestly, I’d call this answer close to canonical. It’s definitely superior to other answers attempting to do the same thing manually. Character-based text manipulation is what regex is designed for and excels at, and the Unicode consortium explicitly standardises the necessary regex features (which ECMAScript happens to implement correctly, in this instance). That said, it fails to handle combining characters (which IIRC regex *should* handle with `.` wildcards).

Comment: Doesn’t work with compositions not built with `U+200D`, e.g. `️‍`. It’s worth noting that composed characters do also exist outside the Emijoi world…

Comment: @StevenPenny ️‍ contains two compositions and one of them does not use `U+200D`. It’s easy to verify that ️‍ does not work with the code of this answer…

Comment: @Holger while its true that ️‍ contains a composition not built with U+200D, its a pretty bad example as it also contains a composition with U+200D. A better example would be something like  or ️

Comment: Conversely to the other comments here, not every use of a zero-width-joiner should be treated as a single grapheme cluster.  For example, the last three lines of the unicode 13 grapheme test (http://www.unicode.org/Public/13.0.0/ucd/auxiliary/GraphemeBreakTest.txt) show three very similar cases where the ZWJ is handled differently.

Answer (score 32):

Alternative solution would be to use `runes` library, small but effective solution:

https://github.com/dotcypress/runes

```js
const runes = require('runes')

// String.substring
'‍‍‍a'.substring(1) => '�‍‍‍a'

// Runes
runes.substr('‍‍‍a', 1) => 'a'

runes('12‍‍‍3✓').reverse().join(); 
// results in: "✓3‍‍‍21"
```

Comment: This is the best answer tbh. All these other answers have cases where they fail, this library (hopefully) meets all edge cases.

Comment: This is funny that such "a simple question" at first look turned to be not an easy task to solve. Agree with Carson - library, hopefully, will move forward with updates and changes as Emojis keeps evolving.

Comment: Looks like this hasn't been updated for about 3 years. Unicode 11 was released about that time, but things have changed since then, with Unicode 13 being released later. There were some changes in the extended grapheme rules in 13. So there might be some edge cases this doesn't handle. (I've not looked through the code - but it is worth being careful with)

Comment: I agree with @MichaelAnderson, this library appears to use a naive or old algorithm. To do this properly it should use the [grapheme segmentation algorithm specified in Unicode](https://unicode.org/reports/tr29/).

Answer (score 28):

You don't just have trouble with emoji, but also with other combining characters.
These things that feel like individual letters but are actually one-or-more unicode characters are called "extended grapheme clusters".

Breaking a string into these clusters is tricky (for example see these [unicode docs](http://unicode.org/reports/tr29/#Default_Grapheme_Cluster_Table)). I would not rely on implementing it myself but use an existing library. Google pointed me at the [grapheme-splitter](https://github.com/orling/grapheme-splitter) library. The docs for this library contain some [nice examples](https://github.com/orling/grapheme-splitter#examples) that will trip up most implementations:

Using this you should be able to write:

```
var splitter = new GraphemeSplitter();
var graphemes = splitter.splitGraphemes(string);
var reversed = graphemes.reverse().join('');
```

---

ASIDE: For visitors from the future, or those willing to live on the bleeding edge:

There is a [**proposal**](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-intl-segmenter) to add a grapheme segmenter to the javascript standard. (It actually provides other segmenting options too).
It is in stage 3 review for acceptance at the moment and is currently implemented in JSC and V8 (see https://github.com/tc39/proposal-intl-segmenter/issues/114).

Using this the code would look like:

```
var segmenter = new Intl.Segmenter("en", {granularity: "grapheme"})
var segment_iterator = segmenter.segment(string)
var graphemes = []
for (let {segment} of segment_iterator) {
    graphemes.push(segment)
}
var reversed = graphemes.reverse().join('');
```

You can probably make this neater if you know more modern javascript than me...

There is an [implementation here](https://github.com/mpcsh/proposal-intl-segmenter-review) - but I don't know what it requires.

Note: This points out a fun issue that other answers haven't addressed yet. Segmentation can depend upon the locale that you are using - not just the characters in the string.

Comment: Looks like the code hasn't been updated for about 2 years - so its tables might not be up-to-date. So you might need to search for something more recent.

Comment: Looks like a more recent fork of this library is available at https://github.com/flmnt/graphemer

Comment: I'm surprised that I had to scroll this far down to see an answer that's actually correct.

Comment: For the proposal example you could do `const graphemes = Array.from(segment_iterator, ({segment}) => segment)`.

Comment: Related: [@rootEnginear's answer to "How can I split a string containing emoji into an array?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71619350/11107541)

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: GraphemeSplitter is not defined

Answer (score 17):

I just decided to do it for fun, was a good challenge. Not sure it's correct in all cases, so use at your own risk, but here it is:

```js
function run() {
    const text = 'Hello world‍‍‍‍';
    const newText = reverseText(text);
    console.log(newText);
}

function reverseText(text) {
    // first, create an array of characters
    let textArray = [...text];
    let lastCharConnector = false;
    textArray = textArray.reduce((acc, char, index) => {
        if (char.charCodeAt(0) === 8205) {
            const lastChar = acc[acc.length-1];
            if (Array.isArray(lastChar)) {
                lastChar.push(char);
            } else {
                acc[acc.length-1] = [lastChar, char];
            }
            lastCharConnector = true;
        } else if (lastCharConnector) {
            acc[acc.length-1].push(char);
            lastCharConnector = false;
        } else {
            acc.push(char);
            lastCharConnector = false;
        }
        return acc;
    }, []);
    
    console.log('initial text array', textArray);
    textArray = textArray.reverse();
    console.log('reversed text array', textArray);

    textArray = textArray.map((item) => {
        if (Array.isArray(item)) {
            return item.join('');
        } else {
            return item;
        }
    });

    return textArray.join('');
}

run();
```

Comment: Well, actually it’s long because the debug infos. I really appreciate that

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh Not a code-golf, but was looking for a more elegant solution. Maybe not like one-liner crazy, but easy to remember. Such as the [regex solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64146120/10289265) is a really good one imho.

Answer (score 3):

Using [Intl.Segmenter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/Segmenter)

```js
const text = 'Hello world‍‍‍‍';

[...new Intl.Segmenter().segment(text)].map(x => x.segment).reverse().join('');

// default granularity is grapheme so no need to specify options
// https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/Segmenter/Segmenter
```

Comment: awesome solution, it's the native js API.

Comment: AFAICT this is still a proposal (https://github.com/tc39/proposal-intl-segmenter) and not supported in all browsers. In particular the tables on the mozilla page show that Firefox does not support it yet.

Answer (score -4):

You can use:

```
yourstring.split('').reverse().join('')
```

It should turn your string into a list, reverse it then make it a string again.

Comment: Did you read the question? Your code is exactly the code OP proved wrong in the question.

Answer (score -5):

const text = 'Hello world‍‍‍‍';

const reversed = text.split('').reverse().join('');

console.log(reversed);